# object literal undefined

Tags: javascript

**Q.js file**

```
Q = {};

Q.stringFile = [];
Q.file = "CSS.txt";

Q.getData = function(Q.file){
    $.get(Q.file, function(data){
        var str = data;
        Q.stringFile = str.split("\n"); 

        return Q.stringFile;
    });
}
```

**a.html file**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Q.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = Q.getData(Q.file);
        alert(d);
     </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

alert doesn't output!

Errors: Q is not defined ; 
unexpected token .

How do i fix this??

Comment: You cannot return data from an Ajax call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Comment: why not?? and why Q is undefined?? it seems as if html doesnt see Q object...

Comment: Because the Ajax is call is asynchronous, i.e. the callback will be called loooong time after the outer function `getData` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you cannot return data from an Ajax call, as the Ajax call is asynchronous. You have to make your function accept a callback, like:

```
Q.getData = function(file, callback){
    $.get(file, function(data){
        var stringFile = data.split("\n"); 
        callback(stringFile);
    });
};
```

and then call it with:

```
Q.getData(Q.file, function(d) {
    alert(d);
});
```

---

Regarding the errors: You have a syntax error in this line

```
Q.getData = function(Q.file)
```

`Q.file` is not valid here. The browser cannot parse and process the file and so `Q` will not be defined.

---

I have the impression, you should first [**read some tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) before you go on.

Comment: but why Q is undefined?? html doesnt see Q.js file??

Comment: Because of this syntax error. If you remove it, `Q` will be defined. As you have this error, the browser cannot correctly parse the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't know about dot formal parameter rule and unreturnable ajax async call.. i learnt now.. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is at:

```
Q.getData = function(Q.file) {
```

The part after `function(` is a formal parameter list and can only contain valid identifiers. They can't contain '.' characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the method definition:

```
Q.getData = function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get(that.file, function(data){
        var str = data;
        that.stringFile = str.split("\n"); 

        // below return has no purpose in an async request
        // return Q.stringFile;

        alert(that.stringFile);
    });
}
```

After running `Q.getData();` your `Q.stringFile` will contain your data;

Also because this function does not return any value, you have to put your alert in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your:

```
Q.getData = function(Q.file) {
```

Is not valid, that's where you define named arguments not where you pass them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object property as function parameter: `Q.getData = function(Q.file){`.  In this case there is no need for a parameter at all because of closure you can read Q.file from inside the `getData` function.

The reason that your alert is returning undefined is that you are making a asynchronous AJAX call it doesn't return anything so d *is* undefined.  If you want to return something from an AJAX call you need to make a synchronous call.

A better solution however would be to use a success handler:

```
var Q = {}; // Without the var it is an implied global.  In this case you look like you want a global, but it's still good form to explicitly define it in the global namespace.

Q.stringFile = [];
Q.file = "CSS.txt";

Q.getData = function() {
    $.get(Q.file, function(data) {
        var str = data;
        Q.stringFile = str.split("\n"); 

        return Q.stringFile;
    }).success(function (d) { // This fires once the data has arrived
        alert(d);
    });
}; // you should have a ; here
```